# How to delete same rows or ranges across multiple sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Say, I want to delete A1:A10 from sheet 1 to sheet 30, where each cell contains different numbers. How to do it all at a time?

Can you please help me with the error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome at SO. It is common to provide a code example for us to look at and provide us with some context. Typically this is called a [mcve]. Can you please edit your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a multisheet delete you can setup the object delO to delete the same range or different ranges in any of the sheets on a spreadsheet
if you want them all to be the same then enter the same ranges

```
function multiSheetDelete()
{
  var delO={sheet1:'A3',sheet2:'A1:A10',Sheet5:'A2:A20',Sheet6:'A1:A4'};
  var keys=getKeys(delO);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=allSheets[i];
    var shtnam=sht.getName();
    if(keys.indexOf(shtnam)>-1)
    {
      var rng=sht.getRange(delO[shtnam]);
      rng.clearContent();
    }
  }
    }

function getKeys(aArray)
{
  var keys = [];
  for(var key in aArray) 
  {
    if(aArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
```